# Crawling some external sites failed

Tags: search, crawling, internet-sites

I'm using Search Server Express + WSS 3.0. I wanna crawl external public web sites. One site is :

http://www.av.se/

When I try a full crawl it is throwing:

*http://www.av.se

Access is denied. Check that the Default Content Access Account has access to this content, or add a crawl rule to crawl this content.*

Local sites and other public sites are getting crawled OK.

What is wrong with that sit?

Can you add it on Content sources and try a full crawl for testing?

Comment: Are these public sites yours?  If so, do you know if any of the technical details are different?  I have never seen Access is denied errors on anonymous content.

Comment: No sir, they are public and are not mines.

Answer (score 1):

Check here... I've ran into this a few times and this KB has really saved me.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Cheers,
Matt B.

Comment: I did try the lookpback stuff. But is not that case here. I'm not crawling my own SharePoint WebApp. It's an external public site that I want to crawl. They are other public sites that my SharePoint server can crawl, but not that one. Why ?